# Coded UI Test Build Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild, coded-ui-tests

I have a lot of coded ui test. I have updated tfs2012. It gives an error when I build it. It was working correct before updating. Where is the problem,thanks. (Test cases were working on test agent machine)

```
Failed to initialize the unit test extension 'urn:CodedUITest': A unit test extension is not registered for the following attribute: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestAttribute.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504849/error-when-executing-visual-studio-unit-tests-without-installing-visual-studio-u

Comment: Probably My issue is different.They were working on test agent machine before updating (tfs2012 -> tfs2012 update2)